# Network icon not visible in Ubuntu and no network connection in Ubuntu VM

Tags: networking, 18.04, vmware

There is no network icon showing in Ubuntu VM. I had tried nmcli network on cmd but there is no change. can you solve this ? and bring back me the network connection

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes need to do `nmcli networking off` and then `nmcli networking on`

UPD:
The following commands actually helped me:

```
ifconfig enp2s0 up
ifconfig enp2s0 inet 192.168.0.14 netmask 255.255.255.0
service networking restart
```

But interface just do not start on boot so I have to do it every time when my laptop booted up.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1242022)